# How to reuse behaviors?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Have two behaviors that change a path's opacity based on its container button's IsEnabled property.  I have several buttons that I want to reuse these two behaviors for that have the same path up to their containers.  How do I do that?

```
<Button x:Name="buttonConcentration">
    <Canvas Width="42.6667" Height="42.6667">
        <Path Opacity="0.2" Width="42.835" Height="42.696" Stretch="Fill" 
        Data="..." UseLayoutRounding="False">
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior 
                    Binding="{Binding IsEnabled,  ElementName=buttonConcentration}" 
                    Value="False">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                <Core:DataTriggerBehavior 
                    Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=buttonConcentration}" 
                    Value="True">
                    <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it on your `Window.Resources`.

Maybe working over this code you'll be able to achieve what you are expecting:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Button x:Key="myButtonConcentration" x:Shared="False">
        <Canvas Width="42.6667" Height="42.6667">
            <Path Opacity="0.2" Width="42.835" Height="42.696" Stretch="Fill" 
            Data="..." UseLayoutRounding="False">
                <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior 
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                        Value="False">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="0.2"/>
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                    <Core:DataTriggerBehavior 
                        Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnabled}"
                        Value="True">
                        <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Opacity" Value="1"/>
                    </Core:DataTriggerBehavior>
                </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </Path>
        </Canvas>
    </Button>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Name="MyButton1" Content="{StaticResource myButtonConcentration}" />
    <ContentControl Name="MyButton2" Content="{StaticResource myButtonConcentration}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: OK, but wouldn't ElementName need to be some kind of relative path (which I couldn't seem to get to work)?